# Reset Git Server Credentials

Tags: github, hana, hana-xs

I am attempting a Push in HANA XSA, and getting an authentication failure. I am following steps from a tutorial https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/xsa-ml-e2e-github-mta.html . I am the admin of the repo and I am sure I am entering the credentials correctly.

From the tutorial, it says User Name and Email are stored on Git Server and I am wondering if this can be reset on the server, or if not how to proceed?

Comment: #1 Are you using https or ssh to clone the repository? # Are you using the github cloud or on-premise? #3 Are you on windows?

Comment: @JRichardsz  https clone from cloud and windows OS